# Python: define multiple variables of same type?

Tags: python

Probably a duplicate, but I can't find the answer by searching with these terms, at least.

Is there a quicker way to do this in Python?

```
level1 = {}
level2 = {}
level3 = {}
```

I've tried

```
level1 = level2 = level3 = {}
```

But that seems to create copies of the object, which isn't what I want. And

```
level1, level2, level3 = {}
```

throws an error.

Comment: *that seems to create copies of the object* - The code `level1 = level2 = level3 = {}` does not create any copies of the dict.

Comment: Just a terminology nitpick, but `level1 = level2 = level3 = {}` is in fact not creating copies.  If it created a copy the behavior would be exactly what you want.  Instead it is assigning all 3 to the same object, not copies of the object.

Comment: @Davy8 I don't think it's nitpicking when someone said the opposite of what they meant to say.

Comment: Also, Python doesn't "define" variables.  It just assigns a name to an object.  What tutorial are you using to learn Python?

Comment: You have gotten tons of solutions, but *why* are you trying to do this? Having to do what you're trying to do is so rare in Python code that I'm thinking you might be having an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your variable naming is a possible sign that your design could be improved. It might be better to use a list instead of three separate variables:

```
levels = [{}, {}, {}]
```

Comment: Or use the list comprehension suggested by @nils: `levels = [{} for _ in range(3)]`

Comment: or for that matter `levels = []` and add your dictionaries as you make them

Answer (score 18):

```
level1 = level2 = level3 = {}
```

Doesn’t create copies. It lets reference level{1-3} to the *same* object. You can use a list comprehension instead:

```
level1, level2, level3 = [{} for dummy in range(3)]
```

or more readable:

```
level1, level2, level3 = {}, {}, {}
```

Comment: In Python vernacular, `dummy` is better indicated by a single underscore `_`

Comment: Not if u want to use `_` for gettext.

Answer (score 13):

You could do

```
level1, level2, level3 = {}, {}, {}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
level1, level2, level3, = {}, {}, {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally never change code to squeeze more stuff on one line. Have three different assignments is the way I would do it, one per line.

However, if there are documented performance improvements by making such a change, that's another thing. I just don't know of any performance improvements with these changes. Only obfuscation.

Answer (score 0):

Python is interpreted which allows the definitions of things to be made at runtime.

```
def prefixed_range(prefix, start, stop=None, step=1):
    " Like xrange() but results are prefixed numeric strings. """
    prefix = str(prefix)
    if stop is None:
        start, stop = 0, start
    for i in xrange(start, stop, step):
        yield prefix + str(i)

def define_vars(names, value=None, namespace=None):
    namespace = globals() if not namespace else namespace
    factory = (lambda: value) if not callable(value) else value
    for name in names:
        namespace[name] = factory()

define_vars(prefixed_range('level', 1, 4), dict)

print 'level1: {}, level2: {}, level3: {}'.format(level1, level2, level3)
# level1: {}, level2: {}, level3: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

People have already answered the intent of your question, but...

> Is there a quicker way to do this in Python?

What do you mean by quicker?

I think your real question *should be* "what is the pythonic way to do this?"

> level1, level2, level3 = {}

From the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange):

> **Tuples are constructed by the comma operator** (not within square brackets), with or without enclosing parentheses, but an empty tuple must have the enclosing parentheses, such as a, b, c or (). A single item tuple must have a trailing comma, such as (d,).

a, b, c is implicitly (a, b, c). That's why you need to have a 3-tuple on the right side as suggested by other posters (nils, sdolan, gunner).

Shown explicitly they are suggesting this:

```
(level1, level2, level3) = ({}, {}, {},)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
level1,level2,level3=[{}]*3

Comment: That would have the same problem.